# Create chart with dynamic data source

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA to create a line chart based on a a dynamic range, I have tried using `CurrentRegion`, however, that threw an error. I then tried using `xlCellTypeLastCell` but that also throws an error.

Is there a way I can amend my code below to achieve this or is there a better way to set a dynamic range?

```
Sub styled_line_chart()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    Set StartCell = Range("AK10")
    'Set dt = Range(StartCell.CurrentRegion.Select)
    
    Dim Lr As Long
    Dim Lc As Long
    Dim FirstCell As Range

    Lr = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    Lc = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    
    Set dt = Range(StartCell, WS.Cells(Lr, Lc))
        
    With ch

        .SetSourceData Source:=dt
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Sales by Year"
        .SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd
        .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone
        .SetElement msoElementLegendTop
        .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone
        .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleBelowAxis
        .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Region"
        .SeriesCollection("Sales 2016").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection("Sales 2017").Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection("Sales 2018").Interior.Color = RGB(50, 0, 0)
        .ChartArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(221, 217, 185)
    
    End With


End Sub
```

Updated:

```
Sub styled_line_chart()

    
        Dim WS As Worksheet
        Set WS = ActiveSheet
    
        Set StartCell = Range("AK10")
        
        Dim lastRow As Long, dt As Range
        
        lastRow = Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set dt = Range("AK10:AN" & lastRow)
        
        Dim ch As Chart
        Set ch = Charts.Add2
        
        With ch
            .SetSourceData Source:=dt
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Sales by Year"
            .SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd
            .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone
            .SetElement msoElementLegendTop
            .SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone
            .SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleBelowAxis
            .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Region"
            .SeriesCollection("Sales 2016").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .SeriesCollection("Sales 2017").Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 0)
            .SeriesCollection("Sales 2018").Interior.Color = RGB(50, 0, 0)
            .ChartArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(221, 217, 185)
        
        End With
    
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: You must show us the range you want to be used. At least, mention which columns. Starting from which row up to the last their cell... Only one series starting from "AK10" up to the last line on that column?

Comment: Try `Set dt = StartCell.CurrentRegion`

Comment: @FaneDuru, it will always be AK:AN, but the rows will be variable, so to the last row

Comment: @CDP1802, unfortunatley that is also throwing an error in the same way

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: @CDP1802 `Run-time '424': Object required` and then highlighting the following row `.SetSourceData Source:=dt`

Comment: Please, build the necessary dynamic range in the way I suggested. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub adaptChartRangeCode()
   Dim lastRow As Long, dt As Range
   lastRow = Range("AK" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   Set dt = Range("AK10:AN" & lastRow)
   
   'your code using dt range...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this is also throwing the following error `Run-time '424': Object required` and then highlighting the following row `.SetSourceData Source:=dt`

Comment: @Maverick  If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? Normally, it should work in this way. When stopped on error and move cursor over `dt` what does it show? Then moving up over the `lastRow` variable, what value does it have?

Comment: Thanks, I realised that I hadn't declared or set my chart. I added that and am now getting the following `Run-time error: '1004' Method 'Add2' of object 'Sheets' failed` - I've done some research, but can't seem to find a fix for this

Comment: @Maverick I cannot keep the step with your way of changing the question. What `Sheets` when you used `Set ch = Charts.Add2`? Try a new testing sub having only two code lines: `Dim ch As Chart` and `Set ch = Charts.Add2`. Does it return any error?

Comment: Apologies. My hope is to get the above working so it will be of use to others also. I have tried running it separately with just those two lines. It is giving the same error and can't figure out why